# SharePoint 2007 calculated column formula: Syntax error

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula, syntax

I have list with a bunch of yes/no checkbox columns. I'm trying to create a column that counts how many fields in the row have the value 'Yes'. I found an inelegant formula that is supposed to do just this - however, SharePoint is telling me that I have a syntax error (perhaps some functions are not supported?). Does anyone have a solution that works with SharePoint 2007?

Here's my current formula:

```
=SUM(IF(EXACT([f1];"Yes");1;0);IF(EXACT([f2];"Yes");1;0);IF(EXACT([f3];"Yes");1;0);IF(EXACT([f4];"Yes");1;0);IF(EXACT([f5];"Yes");1;0);IF(EXACT([f6];"Yes");1;0);IF(EXACT([f7];"Yes");1;0);IF(EXACT([f8];"Yes");1;0);IF(EXACT([f9];"Yes");1;0);IF(EXACT([f10];"Yes");1;0))
```

... which is quite long, so don't read all of it. More notably the shorter variant `=SUM(IF(EXACT([f1];"Yes");1;0))` doesn't even work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the answer about using , instead of ;

However, I also think that the Yes/No field is a Boolean.  This will probably simplify your formula to:

```
=SUM(IF([f1],1,0))
```

Comment: Thank you! You were right; in fact, it seems not to work the original way. (edit: which makes sense, now that I think about it...)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using ";" instead of ","

Try this:

```
=SUM(IF(EXACT([f1],"Yes"),1,0))
```